# Manipulador de Imagens Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, processamento-de-imagens

Existe algum manipulador de imagens parecido com `canvas` ou `jimp` para `node.js`?

**Explicação do porquê não querer usar um dos dois:**
Então, eu estava tentando usar `canvas` como teste, e ele tá a demorar muito para compilar o arquivo, e o `jimp` não escrevia o arquivo ao mesmo tempo que a composição dele. E também demorava muito.

**OBS:** Que contenha como colocar duas imagens e retornar uma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O módulo `gm` é um "wrapper" para GraphicsMagick e ImageMagick pra `node.js`, a grande vantagem é que é muito rápido e te permite fazer tudo que o  ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick  tem a oferecer. A maior desvantagem é que você precisa instalar os binários dos dois separadamente.

Caso opte por utiliza-lo, a função abaixo deve realizar o que deseja:

```
gm("img.png").append("another.jpg", true).write('output.jpg', function(error){})
```

> https://github.com/aheckmann/gm
>
> https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

Comment: Obrigado, testei ontem e realmente é bem rápido